# limits of python in parallel file processing

Tags: python

I've spent the week processing some gnarly text files -- some in the hundred million row range.

I've used python to open, parse, transform, and output these files. I've been running the jobs in parallel, often 6 -8 at a time, on a massive 8-processor, 16-core EC2 unit, using SSD.

And I would say that the output is bad on 0.001% of writes, like:

```
 Expected output:  |1107|2013-01-01 00:00:00|PS|Johnson|etc.

 Actual output:    |11072013-01-01 00:00:00|PS|Johnson|etc.
               or  |1107|2013-01-01 :00:00|PS|Johnson
```

Almost always, the problem is not GIGO, but rather that Python has failed to write a separator or part of a date field.  Thus I assume that I'm overloading the SSD with these jobs, or rather that the computer is failing to throttle python based on write contention for the drive.

My question is this:  how do I get the fastest processing from this box yet not induce these kind of "write" errors?

Comment: Aren't those write errors due to your way of doing things? It's unlikely that the SSD is overloaded. Do you write on the same file from different process / threads?

Comment: Please elaborate on "your way of doing things" -- my way is to write files using csv.writer with a pipe delimiter.   The SSD is handling 50K record writes a second.

Comment: What I meant was, are you writing concurrently to the same file? Because if so, then this would likely be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Splitting master file by lines into smaller pieces.  Processing each piece in parallel, with output going to a corresponding, independent file.  Zero files in common for either reads or writes.  That did need clarification -- thank you for prompting.

Comment: it's possible you're just getting race conditions if you're only using pure threads

Comment: Eiyriou -- would you kindly elaborate on what you mean by "pure threads?"  I have been using "hillbilly" multiprocessing by utilizing Screen -S foo python bar, ctrl-a-d, repeat.  That method may be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `multiprocessing` module (separate processes) or just using threads for the parallel processing?

I doubt very much that the SSD is the problem. Or python. But maybe the `csv` module has a race condition and isn't thread safe?

Also, check your code. And the inputs. Are the "bad" writes consistent? Can you reproduce them? You mention GIGO, but don't really rule it out ("Almost always, ...").

Comment: not using the multiprocessing module -- will investigate, thanks.

I just want to rule out some things, so you and I both "doubt" that the SSD could be the issue, but I'm looking for your experience here -- will device contention for the block device pause processing? will writes be queued?  under heavy load, will characters simply fail to be written?

CSV writer is suspect as is the chance that there is some garbage in the file that is stopping normal processing.  Once I reasonably rule everything else out, GIGO must be the conclusion.

Comment: If the device cannot follow, then `write` will block. So characters won't fail to be written, it'll just wait until the disk is free, and will write.

Comment: The benefit of using the `csv` module is moderately low, so I would probably replace it with self-written code which I would ensure to be thread-safe.  Probably then the problem is gone.  Next task would be to find the reason in `csv`, bugfix it and give the fix back to the community ;-)

Comment: Xaqq -- that is very helpful, particularly in the category of "eliminating paranoia."